# Correct way to attach a power cable to this kind of female plug?

Tags: power, cables, plug

I am trying to figure out how to connect AWG16 power cables to the plug shown in the picture. The plug will be a power source (220V 10A) in a plastic enclosure.
Can I just insert the cables into the plug's "rings", twist them and isolate them with an insulation tape? or there is a better approach?
Thank you.
[image]

[image: Female plug max 10A]

Comment: the power plug and solderless breadboard are like gasoline and fire ... keep the two far apart

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wires should be soldered to the terminals on the socket. I would also add heat-shrink tubing over the connections as insulation.

Just passing the wires through the holes and twisting and taping them will not make a reliable connection.

Comment: @galagomara Breadboards like the one in your picture **are not rated for mains voltage**. This is **extremely dangerous** (people have died this way).

Comment: Sure it is dangerous.  I use the breadboard for voltages <= 9V. Thank you anyway for your remark.

Comment: @galagomara Your photo appears to show a 220V mains socket which you intend to connect to two wires leading to a breadboard. Unless there's a stepdown converter inside that plug, this will energize the breadboard with 220V. If this isn't the situation then I hope you can understand my concern given the photo.